# Google Reporting API V4 Issue

Tags: python, google-analytics

I'm just getting my head around the Google Analytics Reporting API with python and have been trying to get their demo file to work and pull out some data, the full sample code can be found here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

All I have done is simply copied the code and replaced the Key File Location and View ID as instructed within the tutorial, however, I keep getting the error message = "File "HelloAnalytics.py", Line 67  print 'Date range: ' + str(i) 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I was wondering if someone could help me out as my python knowledge is currently very limited.

My code can be found below...

```
    """Hello Analytics Reporting API V4."""

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'test-developments-maps-a9eb7ab2d2cf'
VIEW_ID = '151121821'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.

  Returns:
    An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

  return analytics


def get_report(analytics):
  """Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.

  Args:
    analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  Returns:
    The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()


def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.

  Args:
    response: An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print (header + ': ' + dimension)

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print 'Date range: ' + str(i)
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value


def main():
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: It seems you are using Python 3.x and you need to give parenthesis for `print` function like `print('Date range: ' + str(i))` for every `print` usage.

Comment: Awesome, this has helped solve the invalid syntax problems I have been getting :)