# Why 'sudo pip install' if 'pip install' works? (Issues with HelloAnalytics.py)

Tags: python, pip, google-analytics-api

Google provides a sample HelloAnalytics.py to demonstrate the use of [google-api-python-client](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/).

Below the heading ["2. Install the client library"](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py#pip) they write:

> Use pip, the recommended tool for installing Python packages:
>
> `sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

I wonder why I should use `sudo` while a simple `pip` (without `sudo`) seems to work perfectly (on my Mac):

```
% pip install google-api-python-client
Collecting google-api-python-client
  Using cached google_api_python_client-1.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting six<2dev,>=1.6.1
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting google-auth-httplib2>=0.0.3
  Using cached google_auth_httplib2-0.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.3 kB)
Collecting google-api-core<2dev,>=1.18.0
  Using cached google_api_core-1.20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Collecting uritemplate<4dev,>=3.0.0
  Using cached uritemplate-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting httplib2<1dev,>=0.9.2
  Using cached httplib2-0.18.1-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Collecting google-auth>=1.16.0
  Using cached google_auth-1.17.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Collecting protobuf>=3.12.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.12.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
Collecting pytz
  Using cached pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0
  Using cached requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=34.0.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-api-core<2dev,>=1.18.0->google-api-python-client) (41.2.0)
Collecting googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.6.0
  Using cached googleapis_common_protos-1.52.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3"
  Using cached rsa-4.6-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Installing collected packages: six, cachetools, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, rsa, google-auth, httplib2, google-auth-httplib2, protobuf, pytz, certifi, urllib3, chardet, idna, requests, googleapis-common-protos, google-api-core, uritemplate, google-api-python-client
Successfully installed cachetools-4.1.0 certifi-2020.4.5.2 chardet-3.0.4 google-api-core-1.20.1 google-api-python-client-1.9.3 google-auth-1.17.2 google-auth-httplib2-0.0.3 googleapis-common-protos-1.52.0 httplib2-0.18.1 idna-2.9 protobuf-3.12.2 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pytz-2020.1 requests-2.23.0 rsa-4.6 six-1.15.0 uritemplate-3.0.1 urllib3-1.25.9
```

Is that sample simply outdated? (They use `print` without `()` though [Python 2.7 seems to be deprecated for google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client#deprecated-python-versions) which [confused others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493828/google-reporting-api-v4-issue) already.)

I fixed that and still get an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client'`. Am I right that the missing `sudo` is not the cause for that?

Well, and they do not explain what a `VIEW_ID` is and where to get this.

Comment: Not using 'sudo' I believe has to do with how your system is or was configure to use the 'pip' tool and for the other issue you will need to let google know this

Comment: Re sudo - it depends on whether the sticky bit is set in pip.  On some linux variants, the sticky bit is not set.  Maybe it is set on the macs.  Do a *ls -l* where pip is installed and see if s is set.

Comment: Whether you use `sudo` depends on whether you are attempting to update the system python installation. Are you running a local install of python or a virtual environment?

Comment: @cup sticky bit or setuid bit? I checked my ubuntu 19.10 and setuid was not set. I would be annoyed if it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works without sudo for you because you seem to have python installed in a location where your user has write permissions.

```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=34.0.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-api-core<2dev,>=1.18.0->google-api-python-client) (41.2.0)
```

It all depends on how and where you install python. The mac os distro python is installed in `/Library/` which is owned by root. So if you want to install a new package, you will need to use sudo.